# How to Time a Repeating Operation in a Page

Tags: windows-phone-8

So a new concept came to mind of timing an operation within the code behind of a page. I am presenting a slideshow of sorts, and every few seconds I would like to rotate the images on a page from left to right. What I want to do is place a pivot control in a page, insert the images into each PivotItem, and every 3 seconds set the SelectedItem index of the Pivot control to the next available index, and repeat continuously.

How might I time the operation to change the selected PivotItem indices?

EDIT

Constructor

```
//  DispatcherTimer setup
dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,3);
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

How to set up event handler to continuously rotate PivotItems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`DispatchTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx) object.  This will ensure that when your `Tick` callback is called it is called on the UI thread and you can perform actions on page controls without causing an exception

Comment: Great idea. I've added an edit. Could you suggest an optimal way of looping through the PivotItems?

Comment: Do you have an independent collection of `PivotItem`s or is this just going to the next pivot item in a `Pivot` control?

Comment: It would be the next pivot item, and cycle through hypothetically three pivot items in a single Pivot control named `Pivot` every three seconds.

Comment: Probably something like `Pivot.SelectedIndex = Pivot.SelectedIndex + 1 >= Pivot.Items.Count ? 0 : Pivot.SelectedIndex + 1;`  But, I'm assuming changing SelectedIndex *does* visually show a different PivotItem;